# Problem with libmysqlclient.so.18 MySQL

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to run a 5.7 MySQL server in my ubuntu 18.04 server.
When i run the application that uses MySQL it tells me that this file "libmysqlclient.so.18" or directory does not exist. I tried looking for it online but nothing i tried helped me.
Hoy an i fix this issue? I have almost no experience with Ubuntu

Comment: Did you install the client part of MySQL? (`sudo apt install mysql-client`)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you're missing a library package. This should get you running:

1. Update `apt`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install the library package that contains `libmysqlclient.so.18`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install libmysqlclient18
   ```
3. (Optional) Restart MySQL:

   ```
   $ sudo service mysql restart
   ```

This should be all you need to do